# Search files according to extension and date using Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a search through my files looking for HTML and the latest modified date, the format I'm trying to output is:

path to file and filename, date last modified - sorted in alphabetical order. (`X:\mydirectory\myfile.html, 18-09-2014 18:15`)

I have used the following string but for some reason I cannot get the last modified date of the file and even if I moved around the attributes I don't understand where I'm failing.

```
dir X:\*.html /s /o:n /t:w /b /a:-d   >> "X:\list-all-html-files.txt"
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you actually using MS-DOS (and if so, which version)? Note that a Windows command prompt is **not** "MS-DOS" or "DOS".

Comment: hi, you are right it is the Windows Prompt command version 5.2.3790, my apologies for the mistake and thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below command to get the files which are modified a day before today.

Z:>FORFILES /s  /M *.html /C "cmd /c echo @path was changed on @fdate @ftime" /D -1 >> C:\PerlCompiler\list-all-html-new-999.txt

For more reference please go through the link http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

FORFILES.exe (Native command in Vista/Windows7/2008, via Resource Kit for XP)

-
Vinay Mishra

Comment: Feeling old... I did not know about that having been incorporated as native.  +1 for simple solution (apparently it defaults to alphabetic sort as well).

Answer (score 0):

The `/b` output is just a plain filename with path so there's no date information there.  Also your syntax is a bit odd (don't need colons, for example) though it'll work.  Meanwhile let's take it a step at a time.

My approach to get just the filenames (first test step) would be:

```
dir x:\*.html /s | find ".html" | sort > X:\list-all-html-files.txt
```

You don't need the quotes around the output filename in this case because there are no spaces; otherwise that's fine and a good idea.  The last modified date is the date provided by default in the DIR output so you don't need to specify `/tw` either.  You're going to want to sort the output because it's going to be scanning through various directories, rather than just making sure the names within each directory are sorted with `/on`.  Assuming you aren't really appending to another file, you'd want to use `>` instead of `>>` so each run starts fresh, or use the code below to delete the output before starting.  You also don't need `/a-d` (I don't think) because you're specifying an extension of `.html`, unless you think you could have an unlikely directory name that has an `.html` extension.

But you say indeed you need the full paths plus the details, so you need to use a FOR loop and extract the name, then individually go get the rest of the information.  Assuming it's in a batch file (which is why I used %%I instead of %I).  The `%%~ti` provides the timestamp and %%~dpnxI produces a concatenated drive + path + filename + extension:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set OUTFILE=list-all-html-files.txt
if exist %OUTFILE% del %OUTFILE%
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir x:\*.html /s /b ^| sort') do echo %%~dpnxI   %%~tI >> %OUTFILE%
endlocal
```

I used a local variable OUTFILE so it could be defined once but used in several places in the code.  There's a TAB character between the `%%~dpnxI` and `%%~tI` to make the output something you could paste into e.g. Excel.

Comment: Hi I tried the suggested approach but it did not work for some reason, most likely as I'm not really experienced with the Windows prompt command and batch files, I thank you for the help provided

Comment: That's fine--you bit off a rather large chunk for a beginner!  Do you get errors?  I tested the above but of course with different paths and filenames so though I think it should work I might have fumbled something.  Let us know what seems to be going wrong and maybe something will jump out at us.